# How to compare datetimes if they are with different offset (timesones)?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

how should the datetime comparison  work if the datetimes are in diff timezones.

For example:

```
WITH datetime("2022-11-01T08:00+01:00") AS d1, datetime("2022-11-01T07:00") AS d2
RETURN d1=d2
```

returns false!?

I am using 4.4.12 community edition under OSX.

Even more strange is the following:

```
WITH datetime("2022-11-01T08:00:00+01:00") AS d1, datetime("2022-11-01T07:00") AS d2
RETURN duration.between(d1,d2)
```

Result: PT0S

```
WITH datetime("2022-11-01T08:00:00+01:00") AS d1, datetime("2022-11-01T07:00") AS d2
RETURN d1.year, d2.year, d1.month, d2.month, d1.day, d2.day, d1.hour, d2.hour, d1.minute, d2.minute, d1.second, d2.second, d1.millisecond, d2.millisecond, d1.timeZone, d2.timeZone, d1.offset, d2.offset, d1.epochMillis, d2.epochMillis
```

The hours, offset and timezone is different for d1 and d2.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing two `Datetime` objects, with differences in their properties, it won't work. You can simply compare the `epochMillis` of the two objects, to compare that the two date times are equal, regardless of the timezone:

```
WITH datetime("2022-11-01T08:00:00+01:00") AS d1, datetime("2022-11-01T07:00") AS d2
RETURN d1.epochMillis = d2.epochMillis
```

If you compare two `datetime` instances, at the exact same time, in the same timezone the comparison works, as expected:

```
WITH datetime("2022-11-01T07:00:00") AS d1, datetime("2022-11-01T07:00") AS d2
RETURN d1 = d2
```

So, the behavior you are seeing is correct, because to compare composite objects you need to compare all the key-value pairs within them.

Comment: But those two datetimes are equal and equals should be internally implemented through epocMillis. Although what you are suggesting is correct, can only be seen as a workaround IMO.

Comment: The reason we have to go via this path is because of the implementation differences between the databases. Neo4j is storing each and every piece of information internally, like timezone, while RDBMS like MySQL stores just timestamps and we have to add a separate column for timezone. So, this is the best way here

Comment: but my question is solely related to neo4j and cypher.

Comment: Yupp. I am just giving an example. I have updated the answer to why DateTime comparison in neo4j is working this way. One other alternative can be to store timestamps and timezone, in two different properties, of a node, so direct comparison will work.

Answer (score 0):

Charchit's answer is fastest way to do the comparison. Alternatively, you can also use duration function to compare the difference in seconds like below.

```
WITH datetime("2022-11-01T08:00+01:00") AS d1, datetime("2022-11-01T07:00") AS d2
RETURN duration.inSeconds(d1, d2)=duration({seconds: 0})
```

will return

```
╒═══════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"duration.inSeconds(d1, d2)=duration({seconds: 0})"│
╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│true                                               │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I already mentioned in the second example query of my original question.

Comment: thaks I missed that part. PT0S means temporal time of zero seconds